# Starting a new instance of GDM in Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, gdm

In Fedora 18, I could use `gdmflexiserver` to start up a new instance of X and GDM on a new VT.  In Fedora 19, `gdmflexiserver` appears to have lost the ability to do this, and I'm looking for its replacement.

Answer (score 0):

By Fedora 22, it's not necessary to spin up a new instance of GDM to log in a second time, as user sessions run on a separate VT.  In the default configuration, VT-1 holds GDM, and the first user session is on VT-2.